Is it okay to upload a manuscript to arXiv while it is under review?
I have two papers currently under review: one in an IEEE journal and the other in a Taylor & Francis journal. I forgot to upload them to arXiv before submitting to the journals.
Is it acceptable to upload these papers to arXiv now, considering I have revised them based on reviewer comments?
Both IEEE and Taylor & Francis permit preprints on arXiv, but I’m unsure whether the revised versions still qualify as preprints, given the changes made after reviewer feedback.
Edit: IEEE was okay with me uploading to arxiv. Taylor&Francis was also okay, but they wanted to upload to arxiv on behalf of me and asked for the details of changes made to the paper.

Ask the respective editors. Some journals are more positive than others, but some are not. The original submission, prior to review might be more likely, but the editor will know.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_publishers_by_preprint_policy

This can depend heavily on the policies of the particular journal. For research journals in mathematics, sometimes one can submit to a journal a paper that's been on the arXiv for a while, directing the editors' attention to the posting on the arXiv rather than sending them the paper. For the American Mathematical Monthly, the policy forbids posting to the arXiv until some time after publication (three years, I think?).

It seems unlikely to me that either journal would approve of you uploading to arXiv the manuscript in a form that has been revised in accordance with the advice of their reviewers. Whether or not they would accept a post-submission upload to arXiv of the manuscript as originally submitted to them is something you would need to check with an editor.
There are two common reasons for authors uploading their manuscript to arXiv, neither of which fits your circumstances:

To make the paper available to other experts so that they can critique the paper before the author submits it to a journal
To make the paper publicly available (i.e., open access) without any intention of either revising the paper or submitting it to a journal.

In your case, it appears (whether or not this is really the case) that you are retrospectively trying to provide an open-access form of the paper having submitted it to two journals that are likely to want to put the paper behind a paywall. Of course, if you have in fact submitted to an open-access journal where a Creative Commons licence applies, then you will be able to archive a copy of the published article wherever you wish. ... and even if you have submitted to a paywall journal, they might have a policy of allowing authors (post publication) of making available an uncorrected proof copy of the paper on the authors own website.
